# Flutter App crashes, the package bluetooth_print can't print images on ios, it's working in android but doesn't work in iOS

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-printing

I'm using this package`bluetooth_print: ^4.3.0` in my flutter app, but it crashes the app when trying to print images.

Here is the error message in xCode:

```
Exception   NSException *   "UIGraphicsBeginImageContext() failed to allocate CGBitampContext: size={0, 0}, scale=1.000000, bitmapInfo=0x2002. Use UIGraphicsImageRenderer to avoid this assert."   0x00000002837dae50
```

Comment: It looks like that plugin is using the deprecated `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` - This method crashes if you try and initialise it with a size of [`0,0`](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733326) - If you are trying to print an image, make sure you aren't sending dimensions of 0,0